# Can we use modal verbs of requests such as **would**, **could**, and **can** with a third-person word?

Tags: modal-verbs

**Question:**

Can we use modal verbs of requests such as **would**, **could**, and **can** with a third-person word?

**Example 1:**

> **Would** **your son** close the window? I feel cold.

**Example 2:**

> **Could** **your boss** answer my question?

**Example 3:**

> I heard your son is good at brewing tea. **Can** **he** brew tea for me?

**Example 4:**

> **Would** **your children** **like** to sit next to my son? They are good friends.

Comment: Rather than "Can we...", if I rephrase your question as: "Would the following examples be understood as requests, even though they have third person subjects?", is that the question you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

It's not usual to phrase a request through a third person.

1. as a request, would be expressed as

> Would you have your son close the window?

2. and 3. are questions about whether another person is able to do something. They aren't requests.

Example 4. Is a question about whether the children would like to do something, or an invitation, but not a request.